# 2 dependent datepickers with min and max date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm looking to build a form with 2 datepickers. The chosen data of the first one, must be the minDate of the second one and the maxDate of the second one must be the minDate+10 days.

For example:

- first date selected: 01/01/2019
- In the second field I can choose maximum the 01/10/2019 as date

Here is my little code I've done just now:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#from").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
        minDate: 0,
        onSelect: function (date) {
            var date2 = $('#from').datepicker('getDate');
            date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 10);
            $('#to').datepicker('setDate', date2);
            //sets minDate to from date + 1
            $('#to').datepicker('option', 'minDate', date2);
        }
    });
    $('#to').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
        onClose: function () {
            var from = $('#from').datepicker('getDate');
            console.log(from);
            var to = $('#to').datepicker('getDate');
            if (to <= from) {
                var minDate = $('#to').datepicker('option', 'maxDate');
                $('#to').datepicker('setDate', minDate);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry I forgot it

Comment: What, exactly, are you struggling with?

Comment: As I said i'd like a dependecy among them. But with my code is not the dependence I'd like to have

Comment: Make sure you don't mis-match your date formats.  Your `dateFormat` attributes are set to `dd-M-yy` but your example dates in your explanation appear to be `mm/dd/yyyy`

Comment: I suggest you to don't set the max date for the from field, since i had a similar problem, and it will create some problem.

Let's think that you choose from 2019/01/07, than the to min will be 2019/01/08; now if you choose the to like 2019/01/10, the from will be at max the 2019/01/10 too.
Now there will be a problem, since you cannot set a date after 2019/01/10 anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
$("#from_date").datepicker({
    format: 'yyyy/mm/dd',
    autoclose: true, 
    }).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
        var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
        var someDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
        var numberOfDaysToAdd = 10;
 someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd);
        var dd = someDate.getDate();
 var mm = someDate.getMonth() + 1;
 var y = someDate.getFullYear();
 var someFormattedDate = y + '/'+ mm + '/'+ dd;

        $('#to_date').datepicker('setStartDate', minDate);
        $('#to_date').datepicker('setEndDate', someFormattedDate);
    });

$("#to_date").datepicker({     
    format: 'yyyy/mm/dd',
    autoclose: true,
    }).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
        var maxDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
        var someDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
        var numberOfDaysToAdd = 10;
 someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() - numberOfDaysToAdd);
 var dd = someDate.getDate();
 var mm = someDate.getMonth() + 1;
 var y = someDate.getFullYear();
 var someFormattedDate = y + '/'+ mm + '/'+ dd;
        $('#from_date').datepicker('setStartDate', someFormattedDate);
        $('#from_date').datepicker('setEndDate', maxDate);
    });
```

```html
<!-- Css Link -->
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- js Link-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

From Date:-
<input type="text" name="" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" id="from_date" placeholder="Select Date">
<br>
<br>
To Date:-
<input type="text" name="" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" id="to_date" placeholder="Select Date">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the `to` date from +1 day from selected date to +10 day from selected date, this should work:

```
 $("#from").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    minDate: 0,
    onSelect: function (date) {
        var selectedDate = $('#from').datepicker('getDate').getDate();
        var minDate = new Date();
        // set min date
        minDate.setDate(selectedDate  + 1);
        var maxDate = new Date();
        // set max date
        maxDate.setDate(selectedDate  + 10);
        $('#to').datepicker('setDate', minDate );
        //sets minDate to from date + 1
        $('#to').datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate );
        //sets maxDate to from date + 10
        $('#to').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', maxDate );
    }
});
```

Comment: sorry it doesn't work for me. It doesn't open the "to" datepicker

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to GiuServ I found the solution.

Here the code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#from").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
        minDate: 0,
        onSelect: function (date) {
            var date2 = $('#from').datepicker('getDate');
            var minDate = new Date();
            // set min date
            minDate.setDate(date2.getDate()  + 1);
            var maxDate = new Date();
            // set max date
            maxDate.setDate(date2.getDate()  + 10);
            //sets minDate to from date + 1
            $('#to').datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);
            $('#to').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', maxDate);
        }
    });
    $('#to').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
        onClose: function () {
            var from = $('#from').datepicker('getDate');
            console.log(from);
            var to = $('#to').datepicker('getDate');
            if (to <= from) {
                var minDate = $('#to').datepicker('option', 'minDate');
                $('#to').datepicker('setDate', minDate);
                var maxDate = $('#to').datepicker('option', 'maxDate');
                $('#to').datepicker('setDate', maxDate);
            }
        }
    });
});
```