# how to make 5 days disable after user current date selection excluding weekends

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

suppose i have selected 17/01/2019 then  5 days must be disable. this date must change dynamically according to date selection.

```
$('.datepickstart').datepicker({
     autoclose: true,
     todayHighlight: true,
     format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
     daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
     startDate: date
    });
    $('.datepickstart').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(e) { 
        var temp = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
      var d = new Date(temp);
      console.log(d);
      d.setDate(d.getDate() + 5);
      console.log(e.date);
      $('#datepickstart').datepicker('maxDate',e.date);
    });
```

Comment: have u tried  $('.datepickstart').on('change', ?

Comment: yes i have try above code with on change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setStartDate instead of maxDate

```
$(".datepickstart").datepicker({
     autoclose: true,
     todayHighlight: true,
     format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
     daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
     startDate: date, 
    }).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
            var temp = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            var numberOfDaysToAdd = 5;
            temp.setDate(temp.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd);
            $('.datepickstart').datepicker('setStartDate',temp);
});
```

and check this Maybe you will get some help

[2 dependent datepickers with min and max date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54077652/2-dependent-datepickers-with-min-and-max-date/54109144#54109144)