# How do I display the end date 31-03- year(depending upon the start_date)?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a two date picker. In the first date picker is a start date and second date picker is an end date.

My year range is

```
2018-2019 (Last date is 31-03-2019)
2019-2020 (My start date is 01-04-2019 and the end date is 31-03-2020)
2020-2021 (My start date is 01-04-2020 and the end date is 31-03-2021)
   //and so on
```

Now according to the current year, we are in the range of 2018-2019.

So my end date will be the 31-03-2019.

How do I display the end date 31-03- year(depending upon the start_date)?

Should I need some jquery or PHP to handle this?

```js
$(function() {
  var year = (new Date).getFullYear();

  $(".start_date").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonText: "Select date",
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    minDate: 0,
    //maxDate    :  "+1Y",
    maxDate: new Date(year, 03, 31),
    // maxDate: "+3m"
    showAnim: "clip",
    numberOfMonths: 1
  });
  $(".end_date").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonText: "Select date",
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    minDate: 0,
    //maxDate    :  "+1Y",
    maxDate: new Date(year, 03, 31),
    showAnim: "clip"
    //numberOfMonths: 2
  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Start Date</label>
  <input type="text" name="start_date" placeholder="Start Date" id="start_date" class="start_date form-control">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>End Date</label>
  <input type="text" name="end_date" id="end_date" placeholder="End Date" class="end_date form-control">
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Would you help me out in this?

Comment: Why not `maxDate: new Date(year + 1, 03, 31)`

Answer (score 0):

You can, using `onSelect` option, set the `maxDate` in the `.end_date` datepicker.

```js
$(function() {
  var year = (new Date).getFullYear();

  $(".start_date").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonText: "Select date",
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    minDate: 0,
    //maxDate    :  "+1Y",
    maxDate: new Date(year, 03, 31),
    // maxDate: "+3m"
    showAnim: "clip",
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onSelect: function(dt, dp) {
      var selected = $.datepicker.parseDate("dd-mm-yy", dt);
      var yy = selected.getFullYear();
      var mm = selected.getMonth();
      var dd = selected.getDate()
      var nextYear = $.datepicker.parseDate("dd-mm-yy", "31-03-" + (yy + 1));
      $(".end_date").datepicker("option", "maxDate", nextYear);
    }
  });
  $(".end_date").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonText: "Select date",
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    minDate: 0,
    //maxDate    :  "+1Y",
    maxDate: new Date(year, 03, 31),
    showAnim: "clip"
    //numberOfMonths: 2
  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Start Date</label>
  <input type="text" name="start_date" placeholder="Start Date" id="start_date" class="start_date form-control">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>End Date</label>
  <input type="text" name="end_date" id="end_date" placeholder="End Date" class="end_date form-control">
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Since we get the date in string, we can use `$.datepicker.parseDate()` to parse it into a Date and increment the year into a new Date.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Can you share the output because I checked your snippet but not getting the expected output.

Comment: Give me some time to check.

Comment: My last two scenarios is working the only issue with the first one. if the start date is 21-01-2019 then end date should not exceed the 31-03-2019.

Comment: @user9437856 I am unable to determine what the three scenarios are and what dates should results in specific ranges. You have `2018 - 2019` and `2019 - 2020`, but it's not clear where the cut over is. Do you mean `01-01-2018` to `31-12-2018`? Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation. I will explain you in details. I have two dates startDate and endDate. My cut of date is 31-03. Now if user select startDate 01-04-2019 the endDate will be 31-03-2020 (which is working with your answer) but if I choose startDate 10-01-2019 the endDate should be 31-03-2019.

Comment: check this Maybe you will get some help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54077652/2-dependent-datepickers-with-min-and-max-date/54109144#54109144

Comment: @DarpanPatel, Thanks for the link, My scenario is different, Above answer is working for me but not 100%. There is some little bit issue.